# shared folder route in ASP.Net, Framework 2.0

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, shared-directory

I have this problem:
I have a web application that was working ok on accessing shared folder in same server application, but outside of application folder.
The route of shared folder is stored in a table (SQL Server 2008 R2), this is query using sqlcommand and datareader, including credentials to access the shared folder.
Suddenly that part of application stop working, the problem I found is that the path of shared folder appears without the char '\', something like this `\IP_SERVERsharedfolder` altough in database it is stored as `\\IP_SERVER\sharedfolder`, if the query is executed on sql server managment, it displays the whole path.

Do you have experienced a similar problem.

I appreciate your help.

The problem here is not how to access the shared folder, that means, the problem is when the path is gotten from database where it is stored, I use a data reader object to get from database:

```
If dtrReader.HasRows Then
    fldPath = dtrReader(3).ToString
    username = dtrReader(4).ToString
    password = dtrReader(5).ToString
End If
```

in variable `fldPath` , I got `\IP_SERVERsharedfolder` instead `\\IP_SERVER\sharedfolder`, char `\` is removed.

Comment: You should add the code you use to get the shared folder.

Comment: Thanks por your reply.